# Android app on cold start not using selected DayNight mode for Preview Window

Tags: android, splash-screen

Our app has two themes day and night. I tried to use `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight`. Then in App class I set preferred DayNight mode. But still not getting selected theme background color during app cold start. 
Is there a way system can show Preview Window(during [Zygote trick](https://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/)) with selected theme(Day or Night) background color.